# Simplifying expression of fractions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to simply $\frac{H^{\xi}\left(\frac{H}{H_0}\right)^{-\xi}}{H_0}$ this term to be $H_0^{\xi-1}$,

I run the code FullSimplify and Cancel but they do not work

```
Cancel[((H^\[Xi]) ((H/H0)^-\[Xi]) )/H0]
FullSimplify[((H^\[Xi]) ((H/H0)^-\[Xi]) )/H0]
```

How should I do that?

Answer (score 5):

```
expr = ((H^ξ) ((H/H0)^-ξ))/H0
PowerExpand[expr]
```

> $\text{H0}^{\xi -1}$

Comment: Thank you so much!